# Easiest way to ensure browser cache is cleared when debugging EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This is driving me nuts.

Everytime I make a change I'm having to ensure the most up to date javascript include is loaded by the browser (same behaviour chrome and FF)...

ctrl + f5 has no effect, i have to manually clear the browser cache - which is a nightmare

I have this code in my app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true,
  disableCaching: false
});
```

**Edit: Chicken & egg scenario:**

- in order to be able to set breakpoints in FF or chrome you need to
  turn on caching (see code above) so that the '_dc' querystring
  parameter is not added to the script file
- but then you always get a cached copy, so u dont see your changes
  anyway
- if you turn off caching, then you can't set breakpoints, because the browser sees it as a new url

Anyway round it?

Comment: Why am I not getting the same behaviour? I'm using Chrome; my `Ext.Loader.setConfig();` is within `Ext.onReady` before the app declaration; The scripts that are not cached (no `_dc`) refresh alright, and I can set breakpoints in them, and get the breakpoints even after refresh / code updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've turned off the cache breaker for the same reason. My solution is to also turn off Firefox's cache entirely. (It's a dev machine so I really don't need it at all)

1. Go to "`about:config`" in Firefox and search for "`cache`".
2. Set `browser.cache.offline.enable` to `false` (double click on it)
3. Set `network.http.use-cache` to `false`
4. If you use `ext-all-dev.js`, set `extensions.firebug.cache.responseLimit` higher than it is to ensure you can see all of the source in Firebug.

You may need to restart and clear the cache after doing this. But, Firefox will then pull the latest source every time you load the page (`F5`), and breakpoints will get hit in Firebug.

If this isn't acceptable, you can also temporarily insert `debugger;` statements into your code, which will act as breakpoints. Put them inside `if`s to act as conditional breakpoints.

Comment: You're welcome, this is one of the things that drove me nuts about switching to Ext 4. Another thing, though this might have been fixed for 4.1: when using ext-debug and variants instead of ext-dev, Loader failures would be silent. It took me a long time to find out I needed to use dev and then it would tell me exactly what was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome. Press F12 to bring up the Developer Tools window. Then Right Click on the browsers refresh icon. You should now have the following options:

- Normal Reload
- Hard Reload
- Empty Cache and Hard Reload

Click on "Empty Cache and Hard Reload", that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you can do:

- Use `console.log()` to debug information you need instead of stopping at break points.
- Add `alert()` in the beginning of you app, and when it will be paused - set the breakpoints to already loaded files.

Comment: not exactly efficient...being able to breakpoint and examine live values is what makes or breaks its

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) extension for FireFox and Chrome to enable/disable/clear caches quickly.